# Flutter Future<bool> I want to return boolean value

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new in Flutter, I am trying to get it from StatelessWidget Class, but it's not allow me to get return value from Future Method, How do i get return value?

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Widget _defaultPage = userLogin();
  var loginStatus = isLoggedIn();
  print(loginStatus);
    if(loginStatus == true){
      _defaultPage = NoteList();
    }
  return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: "User notes",
        home: _defaultPage,
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
          '/login': (BuildContext context) => new userLogin(),
          '/note_list' : (BuildContext context) => new NoteList(),
          '/note_detail' : (BuildContext context) => new NoteDetail(),
        },
      );
  }
}
```

**Future method :**

```
Future<bool> isLoggedIn() async{
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String userId = sharedPreferences.getString("userId");
  bool isLogin = sharedPreferences.getBool("userLoggedIn");
  return isLogin;
}
```

*But it's keep saying Instance of 'Future' in log.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait for it to finish.

```
// in async function
var loginStatus = await isLoggedIn();
```

or

```
var loginStatus;

isLoggedIn().then((onValue){
   loginStatus = onValue;
})
```

in your case you should use future builder

```
home: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: isLoggedIn(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return snapshot.data ? NoteList() : userLogin();
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      })
```

**EDIT:**

```
Future<bool> isLoggedIn() async {
  final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final isContains = sharedPreferences.containsKey("userLoggedIn");

  return isContains
      ? sharedPreferences.getBool("userLoggedIn")
      : throw NullThrownError();
}
```

Comment: It's work first time but when i close app and open it again it return null from function.

Comment: This is probably releated isLoggedIn() function. You should check "userLoggedIn" key before return its value. I made some adjustments your function. Check this out.